# How to install Windows updates from a local WSUS server during Hyper-V Packer build

Tags: hyper-v, packer, windows-update

In building updated base Windows images, I want to install updates from a local WSUS server using the Hyper-V iso builder. I've tried using some of the Windows Update cmdlets in Powershell, but they don't seem to allow for easily adding a WSUS server as the source for update installs.

Answer (score 0):

why not use [WSUS registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

You could [add registry keys](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/10/use-powershell-to-create-registry-keys/) reboot and update the machine using the local WSUS server.

KR

Guenther

Answer (score 0):

I had issues around performing a windows updates, not sure if it's exactly the same issue but this works well for me. I've created some scripts that may help?. The scripts creates a scheduled task, the task installs PSWindowsUpdate and performs and update. You should be able to modify the update script to use `Set-WUSettings`.

[Packer Windows Update](https://github.com/eltimmo/packerWindowsUpdate)